# SUM on LEFT OUTER JOIN on 2 different child tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following table schema

[image]

What I want to do is return all invoices with the following summarized totals

- Total of UnitPrice * Qty for all Line items (e.g. `SUM(UnitPrice * Qty)`)
- Total of Amount for all Additional Costs (e.g. `SUM(Amount)`)

Given that an Invoice can exist without any Line Items or Additional Costs I thought all I would need to do here is use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` i.e.

```
SELECT i.*, SUM(li.UnitPrice * li.Qty) As [Sub Total], SUM(ac.Amount) As [AdditionalCosts]
FROM Invoice i
LEFT OUTER JOIN LineItem li ON li.InvoiceId = i.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN AdditionalCost ac ON ac.InvoiceId = i.Id
GROUP BY i.Id
```

However, the problem is that if both sub tables are of varied length (e.g. I have 4 line items, but only 1 additional cost) the data for the additional cost is repeated across the extra line item rows (and vice versa), you can verify this by removing the `GROUP BY`.

So effectively what happens is for the following record

```
Invoice
-------
400001

LineItem
---------
400001 | 2000 | 100 | 1
400001 | 2001 | 50  | 2
400001 | 2002 | 10  | 10
400001 | 2003 | 20  | 5

AdditionalCost
--------------
1 | 400001 | 30
2 | 400001 | 70
```

My result set would look like

```
Id    | Sub Total  | Additional Costs
--------------------------------------
40001 | 800        | 400 <-- this should be 100
```

How can I calculate the `SUM` of each table independently and combine them into a single master record?

Comment: Have you tried playing round with multiple CTE's to calculate seperate totals and then write a query combining them?

Comment: @SelectDistinct I did but I still couldn't get it to work. I am sure there is a way of doing it using CTE's but it seemed no matter what way I did it it kept giving me the same results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT i.*, li.[Sub Total], ac.[AdditionalCosts]
FROM Invoice i
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(UnitPrice*Qty) As [Sub Total]
                 FROM LineItem
                 GROUP BY InvoiceID) li 
    ON li.InvoiceId = i.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT InvoiceID, SUM(Amount) As [AdditionalCosts]
                 FROM AdditionalCost
                 GROUP BY InvoiceID) ac 
    ON ac.InvoiceId = i.Id
```